# How to solve cron problem in Wordpress?

Tags: wp-cron

I am working with associations using the paid membership Pro plugin but I noticed that the subscriptions are not expiring, I thought that at the beginning it was a plugin problem but I realized that even disabling plugins and themes my posts with scheduling data are not published. Could someone help me how I could do this, I did the test passed in the wp-config function - define ('ALTERNATE_WP_CRON', true); everything seems to work but I see that my url is being changed causing an impact on my SEO for being an unfriendly url. Could someone help me on how can I adjust this cron problem on my wordpress?

Comment: Can you edit your question slightly to help others understand what the actual problem is? You said "my posts with scheduling data are not published" and "my url is being changed causing an impact on my SEO for being an unfriendly url" - maybe you could expand on those problems, with examples of the behavior of a specific post. It is difficult to understand what is being asked.

Answer (score 1):

If your site is using HTTP Authentication (you know, the dialog/prompt that pops up and asks for your username and password), WP Cron will not work. This is because WP Cron does not present the proper login credentials when making the request. To help with this, there is a free plugin that enables WP Cron when HTTP auth is enabled. Check it out at the WP Plugin Directory: "WP Cron HTTP Auth".

Hope this will solve the problem.